# Qt app non-deterministically crashes on calling QMessageBox::question()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am seeing a strange crash in a Qt app that I am working on, and I am wondering if anyone has seen something similar or knows what the reason could be.

The crash is due to an access violation and occurs in around 30% of the cases when a call to QMessageBox::question() is made. The app only crashes in Release mode (never in Debug).

The code that causes the crash looks completely innocuous:

```
QMessageBox::question(
        this,
        QString("Deleting configuration"),
        QString("Are you sure you want to delete this configuration?"));
```

It does not matter if the dialog is created with a static function call (like above) or explicitly. Other standard dialogs that have an icon (QMessageBox::critical(), QMessageBox::information(), etc.) also cause this crash, but interestingly a default QMessageBox dialog without any icons never crashes. However, the crash appears again after adding a standard icon through `setIcon()`:

```
QMessageBox dialog;
dialog.setText("Blah blah blah");
dialog.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
dialog.exec();
```

Could it have something to do with the standard icons in these dialogs? The crash only occurs on the first dialog display; once a single dialog has displayed without a crash, all subsequent ones will work fine.

The Qt version is 5.12.2 and the app is compiled with the Visual Studio 2017 x64 C++ compiler.

Comment: I’ve seen this kind of behavior with uninitialized data members. You can still turn on symbols for your release build and get some kind of stack trace that might provide a clue. It might not have anything to do with the code that crashes but some write before or after an array, use after free or some other pointer misuse that corrupts the heap causing a crash later.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: Thanks. After further searching, it's becoming clear that the crash occurs on the `setIcon(QMessageBox::Question)` call. Still unclear what would be the problem with these standard icons.

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question. The code you've shown is perfectly fine. You'll need to use the visual studio debugger to get a backtrace of the crash.

Comment: @NikosC. : unfortunately I've never been able to replicate this crash when the app is running in a debugger. It just works normally. I've been able to narrow it down to the `setIcon(QMessageBox::Question)` call, but I can't go any further than that. My hope was that someone has seen this same exact issue before.

Comment: Can you replicate the crash with a minimal "hello world" Qt application that just has a QMainWindow and shows a message box?

Comment: I could not replicate it in a minimal example the first time I tried, but now that I think of it, I wasn't setting the same style, and Qt docs say that the standard icons are provided by the styles.

Comment: "unfortunately I've never been able to replicate this crash when the app is running in a debugger" - You do know that you *don't* need a debug build to run it in the debugger - right? You can run your release build in the debugger to catch the crash. And you can build a release build that includes debug symbols to make the debugging experience "not horrible". You can also configure your system to generate a core dump/mini dump/full dump when a crash happens. Then you can run your app as normal and after the crash open the dump in the debugger.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I've tried running the release build on the debugger, and I see that it crashes somewhere deep in the internal Qt calls. It does not help me unless I am willing to actually dive into the Qt code and try to find the bug (or whatever it is that is causing it).

Comment: @PlinyTheElder Diving into the Qt code is actually not that scarry. Build a debug build of qt (or a release build with debug symbols) and you are off to the races. Also, the Qt source is not that scarry to read. It's one of the nicer code bases to debug into / read. It's not OpenSSL or mcop for example 

Comment: In my experience nearly every non-deterministic crash in standard functions is due to memory corruption that happened prior to the call. Debugging memory corruption is hard but I've found it helps to delete parts of the code until the crash disappears or just moving the message box code "up" in your code until it stops crashing.

Comment: @sashoalm: thanks, that's very sensible advice. It looks like this is what I will have to do.

Comment: If you were using GCC or Clang, you could enable their respective sanitizers to see if you get UB somewhere in your code. With VC++, I don't know if it supports that.

Comment: @PlinyTheElder I have also narrowed it down to the `setIcon` call. I was wondering if you knew what was causing it on this old thread?

Comment: Hi @MateoConLechuga, I never found what it was but I have found a workaround. To me this looks like a race condition somewhere in the Qt internals. What I do is to make the following call in the my QMainWindow derived class constructor (before any dialogs are called): style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation). That made the crashes go away. Incidentally, I only saw these crashes on Windows 7. Are you on Windows 7, by any chance?

Comment: @PlinyTheElder No I'm on CentOS. I found out the cause of the issue on my end: I had a static library with a function called "crc32" in it, and the linker/loader did not warn that some other Qt-based library also had a function of the same name, and would just willingly corrupt memory.